# Vaadin ComboBox clearing selection

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin7

I have a ComboBox defined as follows:

```
private final ComboBox classification = new ComboBox( "Class" );
classification.addItem("C");
classification.setItemCaption("C", "Company");
classification.addItem("S");
classification.setItemCaption("S", "Supplier");
classification.addItem("U");
classification.setItemCaption("U", "Customers");
classification.setRequired(true);
classification.setRequiredError("A user class must be chosen!");
classification.setFilteringMode(FilteringMode.CONTAINS);
classification.setTextInputAllowed(true);
```

Whenever I select any value from the dropdown, it immediately clears what I select.  I don't even see it in the "ValueChange" listener.

What is weird is that I copied this form from another one that works perfectly, with a country dropdown.  I am NOT picking an invalid value from the dropdown.  Any idea what is happening?

If not, any idea where I would set a break point in debugger to see where it is getting cleared in ComboBox code?  I tried this once, but sort of got lost in the details.

Comment: If you open browser developer tools, does it show any problem? Try to launch your site ending the url with '?debug' to show vaadin debug window

Comment: No, the '?debug' this did not help - it was one of the things I tried.  To be honest, I did not try the developer tools - forgot.  Regardless, I found the problem and will, assuming my fix keeps working, answer my own question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my own question.  In my case, my problem was caused by the wrapper bean I was binding the fields too.  My bean wraps two "sub-beans", if you will, one for input from an XML, one for output to an XML.  The one for "input" should be filling the form ( calls "get" methods ), but the one for "output" should filling the data from the form ( calls "set" methods ).  This is obviously not ideal, but this is the API I am stuck with.  To fix it, I just made sure that all wrapper "get" methods checked "input" bean first, then "output" bean.  For the "set" methods, I just made sure I set both the "input" and "output" beans.  Like I said, not ideal.

To summarize:  If you see your ComboBox value going away, making sure the bean you are binding to does not undo whatever the ComboBox sets in the corresponding "setter" and "getter" ( under the hood, I believe it sets it, then gets it again ).

Hopefully this helps someone not make the same mistake.